# Alter Access DB Precision property

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to alter Precision property of column that have decimal data type. It is created with Precision of 38, but I want it to be 10. How can I achieve it?

```
Sub MakeDBfile()
Dim daoDB As DAO.Database
Dim daoTable As DAO.TableDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim FileName as String

FileName = "path to file & file name"

'Creates access file using provided path and file name
Set daoDB = DBEngine.CreateDatabase(FileName, dbLangGeneral)
'Creates table
Set daoTable = daoDB.CreateTableDef("RESP")

'Creates columns and their headers
With daoTable
  .Fields.Append .CreateField("darbskaits", dbDecimal)
End With

'Appends table to access file
daoDB.TableDefs.Append daoTable

strSQL = "ALTER TABLE RESP ALTER COLUMN darbskaits DECIMAL(10,3);"
daoDB.Connection.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: Is your database a SQL Server back end or a local table stored in Access itself?

Comment: It is Access file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal fields aren't well supported with JET and DAO. Try connecting either via an ADO/ADODB connection:

```vb
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
cn.Execute "ALTER TABLE RESP ALTER COLUMN darbskaits DECIMAL(10,3);"
cn.Close
```